# Returning a single row on an join

Tags: sql-server-2008

> I have some tables. I want to join them in a way I would like to return the row only from an inner join , but I couldnt find a way to do that.I need help .  How can I get a result like that table using a store prosedure in SQL.Thanks!

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| AltMusteriID | Ad    | Soyad | Gsm1       | Marka | Model | Ozel Alan3 | Ozel Alan4 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1            | İLKER | Yasin | 5337777158 | OPEL  | CORSA | null       | null       |
| 2            | CEM   | ÇİÇEK | 5666667159 | FİAT  | null  | null       | null       |
| 3            | MEHMET| KURU  | 5222237160 | null  |null   |null        | null       |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


 create table tbl_AltMusteriler
(
  AltMusteriID int,
  Ad nvarchar(50),
  Soyad nvarchar (50),
  Gsm1 nvarchar (50)
);

insert into tbl_AltMusteriler values
(1, 'İLKER', 'YASİN','5337777158'),
(2, 'CEM', 'ÇİÇEK','5666667159'),
(3, 'MEHMET', 'KURU','5222237160'),


create table tbl_OzelAlanlar
(
  OzelAlanID int,
  AltMusteriID int,
  UserOzelAlanID int,
  Degeri nvarchar(50)  
);

insert into tbl_OzelAlanlar values
(1,1,1, 'OPEL'),
(2,1,2, 'CORSA'),
(3,2,1, 'FİAT'),


create table tbl_UserOzelAlanlar
(
  UserOzelAlanID int,
  Alan nvarchar(50)  
);

insert into tbl_UserOzelAlanlar values
(1,'MARKA'),
(2,'MODEL'),
(3,'OZEL ALAN3'),
(4,'OZEL ALAN4');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is [PIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), try this

```
;with cte as
(
  select a.AltMusteriID, Ad, Soyad, Gsm1, ALAN, Degeri
  from tbl_OzelAlanlar a
  inner join tbl_AltMusteriler b on a.AltMusteriID = b.AltMusteriID
  inner join tbl_UserOzelAlanlar c on a.UserOzelAlanID = c.UserOzelAlanID
)
select * from cte
pivot(max(Degeri) for alan in (MARKA, MODEL, [OZEL ALAN3], [OZEL ALAN4]))p
```

[SQL DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c3120/6)

Dynamic Pivot:

```
declare @cols AS nvarchar(MAX);
declare @query AS nvarchar(MAX);

SET @cols = stuff((select distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(alan) 
            from tbl_UserOzelAlanlar
            for XML PATH('')) 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = '
;with cte as
(
  select a.AltMusteriID, Ad, Soyad, Gsm1, ALAN, Degeri
  from tbl_OzelAlanlar a
  inner join tbl_AltMusteriler b on a.AltMusteriID = b.AltMusteriID
  inner join tbl_UserOzelAlanlar c on a.UserOzelAlanID = c.UserOzelAlanID
)
select AltMusteriID, Ad, Soyad, Gsm1, ' + @cols + '
from cte
pivot(max(Degeri) for alan in ( ' + @cols + '))p'

exec @query
```

Comment: thank you very much it works great but i want to ask you another question. is that possible to get columns by select tbl_UserOzelAlanlar  except writing columns name by one by (Marka,Model etc.)?